# MC Snippets - Beginner AMPscript Can't get code to output

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to use the [MC snippets tool](https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com) to practice basic AMPscript but I can't get the code to output.

I've tried going through the demo video but couldn't see what's wrong.

Below is a screenshot of my code :

[image: Code screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks.

Comment: Add a directive to output the value 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could output the value inline or you can use the [output](https://ampscript.guide/output) and [concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat) functions inside your block:

```ampscript
%%[

set @IsVIP = AttributeValue("IsVIP")

if not empty(@ISVip) and @IsVIP == true THEN
  set @introsentence = 'Thank you for being a loyal customer for many years'
else
  set @introsentence = 'Thank you for being a loyal customer'
endif

output(concat("<br>",@introsentence))

]%%
```

I'd also wrap that naked `IsVIP` personalization string in [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue) and check for [empty](https://ampscript.guide/empty).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add :

```
%%=v(@introsentence)=%%
```

After the enclosing `]%%`.

This will output the value of the variable `introsentence` inline wherever it is called.